# how to show my slider only homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

hi i have a issue about my slider. i want to show my slider only home page not other sub page. how is it possible ? my code is-

```
                <script>
                $(function(){
                $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
                setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-   child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);

                });
                </script> 

                <div class="fadein">
                <img src="slider/slider1.jpg" />
                <img src="slider/slider2.jpg" />
                <img src="slider/slider3.jpg" />
                <img src="slider/slider4.jpg" />
                <img src="slider/slider5.jpg" />
                </div>
```

Please give me suggestion soon as possible...

Answer (score 0):

How is it even possible that it shows on other pages? Your server might be serving the homepage every time.